# JavaFX css, loaded from a fxml file, doesn't seem to be loading an image

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, javafx-css

So, I am making a project where I need to add a background image to an anchor panel, and I am trying to be clean and use a separate css.

So far my project structure looks like this:

```
D:.
├───.idea
│   └───libraries
├───.mvn
│   └───wrapper
├───src
│   └───main
│       ├───java
│       │   └───name
│       │       └───memoryname
│       └───resources
│           └───name
│               └───memoryname
│                   └───css
│                       └───img
└───target
    ├───classes
    │   └───name
    │       └───memoryname
    │           ├───css
    │           └───img
    └───generated-sources
        └───annotations
```

What interests us, in theory, is this part:

```
memoryname
└───css
    └───img
```

Here, in the memoryname folder, I have my fxml. In the css my css and in img my image.
I have told my css file to do this:

```css
.anchor {
    -fx-background-image: url('./img/Sfondo.png');
    -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Within the fxml, I have called the css file using     `<stylesheets> <URL value="@css/application.css" /></stylesheets>`.

The problem is, even if it doesn't give me any errors or notices, the image does not show up.
If more info is needed I will gladly answer

Edit:
after cleaning and recompiling maven, the output is this:

```
D:.
├───.idea
│   └───libraries
├───.mvn
│   └───wrapper
├───src
│   └───main
│       ├───java
│       │   └───name
│       │       └───memoryname
│       └───resources
│           └───gigliotti
│               └───memoryname
│                   └───css
│                       └───img
└───target
    ├───classes
    │   └───name
    │       └───memoryname
    │           └───css
    │               └───img
    ├───generated-sources
    │   └───annotations
    └───maven-status
        └───maven-compiler-plugin
            └───compile
                └───default-compile
```

Edit 2: Minimum Reproduciple example.
Steps:

1. Create a new JavaFX project with IntelliJ. Include the first two libraries ( BootstrapFX and ControlsFX );
2. You now will have example files. Go to the example fxml file, and with the built-in editor add a new anchorPane, set it's id to 'anchor' and in the Stylesheets text box, write 'style.css';
3. Within the same folder that the fxml file is in, add your image and a CSS file called 'style.css';
4. In the file, add:

```
.anchor {
    -fx-background-image: url('/YOURIMAGENAME.png');
    -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

5. Run your project.

Comment: Did you manually create that file tree, or did you use a tool (e.g., `tree`)? Because it's a little odd. The source directories (under `src`) have `img` as a _child_ of `css`. But the build output (under `target`) have `img` as a _sibling_ of `css`. Which is correct?

Comment: Hi slaw. Yes it was made using tree, I am not sure about why they're put like that, but it might be because that was the disposition at one point when I ran it, So maybe it hadn't updated yet? I have tried running it again and there is still no image in the background, though.

Comment: Note that I have no idea how to reply to messages on StackOverflow. I am hoping I am doing this right.

Comment: Can you try cleaning and rebuilding your project (e.g., `mvn clean` → `mvn compile`)? Then look at the output of `tree` again. Does it still look odd? Also, double-check that the PNG file is ending up in the build output.

Comment: ok, done that  .

Comment: And running the project still results in the image not appearing?

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not appear

Comment: I just tried a similar setup, and everything worked correctly. Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]? Perhaps there's an issue with a part of the code you aren't showing us (e.g., you don't have a node with the styleclass `anchor`, or that node is being covered by other nodes, or that node has no size, etc.).

Comment: Done. Check if it works now

Comment: "_set it's id to 'anchor'_" -- If you've set the **ID** to `anchor`, then in the CSS you need to use `#anchor`, not `.anchor`.

Comment: when I do that, it still doesn't make the image show up.

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce the problem after following those steps. The background image is applied as expected.

Comment: Though I used `./image.png`, not `/image.png`.

Comment: Eden has a [guide on loading resources in css](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/#loading-a-resource-in-css), in case that may help.

Comment: Can you please tell where is your fxml file, css file and the image are located in tree the you provided.